# invertir lista enlazada javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando hacer este ejercicio y cuando corro los test para comprobar si me anda, no me anda. Los test tampoco dice en donde fallo solo me muestra skipped, asi que no se a donde esta el error...

```js
// Agregar al prototipo de LinkedList un método reverseLinkedList que invierta el orden de los elementos de la lista.
// Ejemplo:
// let myList = Head --> [1] --> [2] --> [3] --> [4]
// myList.reverseLinkedList()
// myList = Head --> [4] --> [3] --> [2] --> [1]
LinkedList.prototype.reverseLinkedList = function () {
  // Tu código aca:
 let prev = null;
 let next = null;
 let current = this.head;
 while (current !== null){
  next = current.next
  current.next = prev
  prev = current
  current = next
 }
 return prev;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

te falto asignar el valor de tu variable prev al this.head para que se apliquen los cambios en la lista que te dan. Saludos

```
LinkedList.prototype.reverseLinkedList = function () {
  // Tu código aca:
  let prev = null;
  let next = null;
  let current = this.head;
  while (current !== null) {
    next = current.next;
    current.next = prev;
    prev = current;
    current = next;
  }
  this.head = prev       <= Aqui
  return prev;
};
```